# css for changing a bootstrap nav bar into an accordian in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this html code.

```
div class="container screen-only">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs customNavBars">

            <li class=" marginForFirstElement active" id="listEle1" onclick="changeActiveClass(this)">
                <a href="#" >
                    <div>
                    heading 1
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="listEle2" class="" onclick="changeActiveClass(this)"> 
                <a href="#" >
                    <div>
                    heading 2
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
    </ul>

  </div>

 <div id="listEle1">
  content1
  </div>
   <div id="listEle2">
   content2
  </div>
```

and the corresponding javascript code,

```
  function changeActiveClass(val){
    var idForCheck = val.id;
      check = $( "#" +idForCheck ).hasClass( "active" );
    if(check == false){
       console.log("check == false")
       if(idForCheck == "listEle1"){
          $( "#" +idForCheck ).addClass( "active" );
          $( "#listEle2" ).removeClass( "active" );
          $("#paymentHistoryClass").css("display","block");
          $("#epayments").css("display","none");
     }
       else if(idForCheck == "listEle2"){
            $( "#" +idForCheck ).addClass( "active" );
           $( "#listEle1" ).removeClass( "active" );
           $("#paymentHistoryClass").css("display","none");
           $("#epayments").css("display","block");
        }

    }
  }
```

This code works fine.
But i want the tabs to turn into an accordian when it is in mobile view ,ie screen size less than 992 px.

It should be something like this in mobile view.

```
    -------------------------
    [      heading 1        ]
    -------------------------
    |                       |
    |       content1        |
    |                       |
    -------------------------


    -------------------------
    [      heading 2        ]
    -------------------------
    |                       |
    |       content2        |
    |                       |
    -------------------------
```

Please provide me the css or jscript code to convert the tabs into accordian in mobile view.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: use jsfiddle/codepen to illustrate your problem .

Comment: Bootstrap default navbar already does that. Check the code snippet in their site

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bootstrap tab-collapse: https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse

It's really simple to implement and doesn't require extra code.

Answer (score 0):

sure that it will be much faster

Regards!

[CODE BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/peFUdnwOpZ)

Comment: Your code shows it as an accordion for large screens too.